# Spring 3 -- can't refresh csrf token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, spring-3

I have a production application that will refresh a csrf token like so

```
    private static final String CSRF_TOKEN_SETTER = "window.import.meta.env.CSRF_TOKEN=\"%s\";";

    // sets initial token from request
    @GetMapping(value = "/csrf.js", produces = "application/javascript; charset=utf-8")
    public String csrf(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getAttribute("_csrf") instanceof CsrfToken token) {
            return String.format(CSRF_TOKEN_SETTER, token.getToken());
        }
        return "ERROR";
    }
     
    // used to work, but no longer does after Spring update
    @GetMapping(value = "/refresh_csrf_token")
    public ResponseEntity<String> refreshCsrfToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        CsrfToken newToken = csrfTokenRepository.generateToken(request);
        csrfTokenRepository.saveToken(newToken, request, response);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(newToken.getToken());
    }
```

The FE basically does this:

```
if (statusCodeIs403) {
    refreshCsrfTokenAndAppendToHeadersOfFutureRequests();
}
```

^ this is because we don't want to surface an error or interrupt the session if the csrf token expires. We just want to refresh it and move on.

This *worked* on Spring 2. We recently upgraded to Spring 3 and now something seems to be wrong with our implementation. We're able to set the csrf token initially (with a javascript file) but once the csrf token expires and we refresh the token, we still get a 403 returned. Something must have fundamentally changed between Spring 2 and 3 but it's unclear why the refreshed csrf tokens are failing to validate.

Here's our implementation of the `CsrfTokenRepository`

```
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        tokenRepository.setHeaderName("X-CSRF-TOKEN");
        return tokenRepository;
    }
```

Are we missing a step for saving the token? I also noticed the initial, valid token is a completely different format from the refreshed token:

Valid Token: `sBkVwbeM-hgCeILgJFU6zADrNZkMpcnkG3i0vzqSMIR6MWis1Xgk9Y-6mCkvT-DWE3gO9WPeGPs4xvrJKUqCjQ7wCLEZVF6Z`

Refreshed Token: `3c78e076-9431-4f70-97a8-0aa8760037a7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the diagrams on the updated [CSRF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-components) chapter of the docs for an overview of the work done by the `CsrfFilter`. You are bypassing the filter and therefore don't benefit from the work performed by it.

There are [several JavaScript examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript) but none of them exactly match your customization. My suggestion is to rework your support based on [this example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-other) or [this example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-mobile).

Specifically, notice that you should be injecting a `CsrfToken csrfToken` into your controller method instead of directly interacting with the `CsrfTokenRepository`. For example, you can do like this:

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/refresh_csrf_token")
    public ResponseEntity<String> refreshCsrfToken(CsrfToken csrfToken) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(csrfToken.getToken());
    }
```

Comment: Posted reply as an an answer, couldn't do a code block in the comment

Answer (score 0):

(Couldn't post code in comment)

We ended up doing something similar

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/refresh_csrf_token")
    public ResponseEntity<String> refreshCsrfToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getAttribute("_csrf") instanceof CsrfToken token) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(token.getToken());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
```

I'm guessing this is equivalent, and your suggestion just does the work of parsing out the attribute from the request?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure "parsing" is what's happening. It uses the `CsrfTokenArgumentResolver` built in to Spring Security. Not sure why you'd choose this solution over the one I posted? But it would work (once you fix compile errors).

Comment: I'm fine with either solution, just wanted to make sure they were logically equivalent. We had to do a code patch and had only recently upgraded, so we weren't aware of being able to accept the token directly. 

Thanks for the help!